# Programmatically executing ANT script in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I've built a swing gui in eclipse that is supposed to run a bunch of code previously developed, part of which involves running ant to build the code.  When I run the any script outside of the GUI (in the original project) the ant executes correctly and builds the project.  However when I try and run ant programmatically it throws errors that look like the project doesn't have the necessary .jars.  The code, top of the build.xml, and errors are listed below.

Code Block

```
File buildFile = new File("lib\\ePlay\\build.xml");
    Project p = new Project();
    p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
    DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
    consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
    consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
    consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
    p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);

    try {
        p.fireBuildStarted();
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
        p.fireBuildFinished(null);
    } catch (BuildException e) {
        p.fireBuildFinished(e);
    }
```

Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="EPlay" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" default="resolve">

<dirname file="${ant.file}" property="ant.dir" />
<property name="scm.user" value="scmrel"/>
<property name="scm.user.key" value="/.ssh/scmrel/id_rsa"/>
<property name="ivy.jar" value="ivy-2.0.0.jar" />
<property name="ivy.settings.dir" value="${ant.dir}/ivysettings" />
<property name="VERSION" value="LATEST" />
<property name="tasks.dir" value="${ant.dir}/.tasks" />
<property name="deploy.dir" value="${ant.dir}/deploy" />
...
<!-- retrieve the dependencies using Ivy -->
<target name="resolve" depends="_loadantcontrib,_getivy" description=" retrieve the dependencies with Ivy">
  <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />
  <ivy:resolve file="${ant.dir}/ivy.xml" transitive="false" />
  <ivy:retrieve pattern="${deploy.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

And the error

```
resolve:
BUILD FAILED
H:\eclipse\CLDeploySwing\lib\ePlay\build.xml:66: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -ANT_HOME\lib
        -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs


Total time: 0 seconds
```

I've looked through my ant installation and it *appears* everything is there.  Like I said, the original project builds successfully if build.xml is run outside of this application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this is causde because your java program does not have the same classpath, where it is running, as does the normal ant build - and thus the ANT_HOME isn't the right one.

**You can make sure that this is correct by passing the right enviornmental variables into the JVM, or simply a call to System.getProperty("ANT_HOME"), to see where your ANT_HOME actually is residing.**

Comment: You were correct, 'System.getProperty("ANT_HOME")' returned null.  Just to see if that was the overall issue I put 'System.setProperty("ANT_HOME", "C:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\plugins\\apache-ant-1.8.2");' into the program.  It now shows the correct ANT_HOME but the buildfile still will not build from inside the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think `${basedir}` for your project is not properly calculated.

Add this line to your build.xml

```
<echo message="basedir='${basedir}'/>
```

Looking at this line

```
File buildFile = new File("lib\\ePlay\\build.xml");
```

It may be that it's 2 levels up ( I know the documentation says that it should be a parent directory of build.xml, but you are not running from the command line ).

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you mean here.  Why would the base directory be incorrect if I'm passing along the path to the buildfile?  I put the echo message into the buildfile but it didn't produce an output as the build failed.

Comment: @AndyS. The build clearly fails in Ivy land.  `ivy.jar` property points to a file that is relative to a `basedir`. It would help if you would add `_getivy` target to your listing.

Answer (score 0):

rather than load the ivy library using the new method of using the namespace in the project declaration go old school on it.

```
<path id="ivy.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="path/to/dir/with/ivy/jar" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
<taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
         uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
```

I am doing something in Gradle that requires this

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'ivy-retrieve', classname: 'org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve', classpath: '...path to ivy jar.../ivy-2.2.0.jar')
```

which in ant would be something like

```
<taskdef name="ivy-retrieve" classname="org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve"/>
```

I know it's more klunky and simply not as nice as including the namespace declaration but it does remove some of the confusion regarding which libraries on which classpath are being loaded.